# Regex to find and replace in xcode...?

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, xcode

I have a java file which I got from android, this has some hard coded values in it. Basically we have a file which creates an object of type country and adds it to a list.

I wish to attain the same functionality but I am not sure of the  reg-ex required to find and replace the file contents. 
Basically this is how one of the lines in it looks like...

```
countries.add(new Country("af", "Afghanistan", 93));
```

And this is what I wan't it to look like

```
[countries addObject:[[Country alloc] initWithArray:@[@"af",@"Afghanistan",@"93"]];
```

Do you think regex can be used for such extensive case..? Or will I have to manually do this for every entry..?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do a literal search and capture groups like this and replace them.

**Regex:** `countries\.add\(new Country\("([a-z]+)", "(.*)", (\d+)\)\);`

**Replacement to do:** `[countries addObject:[[Country alloc] initWithArray:@[@"$1",@"$2",@"$3"]];`

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fG8kO8/1)**

Comment: but there is an issue here, xcode doesn't seem to be recognising groups, instead it adds @"1",@"2",@"3"

Comment: Changed it to work on xcode and include all characters.